# Unable to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

This is the error message I get:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, 
E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

How do I force the upgrade to latest package?

I am at 12.04 LTS and want to go to 14.04.1 LTS.  The error message only allows me to close & when doing so closes all of the updater.  from my past recollection there is a file I need to delete.  I can not recall which one.

This machine being used to allow guest to access the internet so there is no risk of data loss.

Comment: User68186 this is not the same issue.  I want to got to the latest version.  Looked at the other question

Comment: Kyodate I looked at your answer and that is not what I want to do. I want to download from the approved trusted site. but the error prevents me from doing so.  closing the error message closes the upgrade box and thus i can not force an update to 14.04.1

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like there is a problem with your package list. This can be
>   solved by running this command in the terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
> ```
>
> This will clear the cache. Now run
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> To update the cache again. After that, please try to upgrade to 14.04
>   again to see if it works now!

Running upgrade now

Thanks to gladen

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04.1 test this:

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo su
cd /var/lib/apt/lists/
rm -r .*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
nano /etc/apt/sources.list

+++ In file, delete the contents of the file and paste the following:
------------------------------------------------------------
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed universe multiverse restricted main
--------------------------------------------------------------
+++ Control + O, save file. Control + X, Close nano. Continue running:
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```